# couldn't allocate usb_device

Tags: dual-boot, usb

First of all, I'm completely new to this, been a Windows user for as long as  I can remember and I've been thinking about dual booting Ubuntu with my Windows 10 for some time now.

I've run into one problem that I can't seem to fix, couldn't find a lot of similar problems on Google either.

I've tried creating a live USB on a 32gb memory device. I've tried etcher, rufus, even netbootin. The boot manager works fine, I boot into the screen where you can choose "Install Ubuntu or "Try Ubuntu Without Installing". I've tried pressing either one but I always get the same error, which is:

```
xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Error while assigning device slot ID

xhci_hcd 0000:02:00.0: Max number of devices this xHCI host supports is 127

usb_usb1-port6: couldn't allocate usb_device
```

Can you guys help? I'm happy to provide all the information I can.

Comment: This is some problem specific to your hardware.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Comment: By hardware you mean USB or every potential part of the computer?

Comment: You didn't give ANY information about the hardware. It may be a problem with USB port, or that error may be irrelevant and the problem is with the video adapter.

Comment: May be a problem with your 32G USB flash drive (or some other USB device... unplug them all). Try another flash drive.

Comment: Nope, still no difference. I don't know what the problem is here...

Answer (score 0):

(it came with a search result, let's leave this for future use)

The problem is solved in my case with added `irqpoll` in file `grub.cfg` as kernel parameter.

If you have a USB-2 port, try to install it from there. After the installation, edit the grub.cfg file to add the irqpoll to the kernel parameter.

Probably it's better to append the `irqpoll` option to /etc/default/grub GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT value.